# about executing *.file in tcl

Tags: cvs, tcl

for this script:

```
puts [exec cvs up *.tcl]
```

I want to cvs updtae all the .tcl file under this folder.

But I always get "cvs update: nothing known about *.tcl" error msg.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

TCL `exec` doesn't glob.  Try `puts [exec cvs up [glob *.tcl]]`

Edit: That doesn't quite work; see the comments.  The following methods do work:

```
# These two don't work with spaces in the names:
exec echo [glob *.tcl] | xargs cvs up
exec bash -c "cvs up [glob *.tcl]"
# Use this instead:
exec bash -c "cvs up *.c"
```

Comment: thank you. but the [glob *.tcl] gave me a string containing all the tcl file names with a space between each other. ie. "xx.tcl yy.tcl zz.tcl". so cvs up xx.tcl yy.tcl zz.tcl will not work. Orz

Comment: I see.  Odd that tcl does this even after splitting the list.  I've found a workaround, though I really don't like it: `exec [glob *.tcl] | xargs cvs up`.

Comment: xargs takes a list of files from the command line and executes its arguments (`cvs up` in this case), adding as many of the files as it can as arguments.

Comment: And note the corrected post; the `xargs` approach won't work if files have a space in their names.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want TCL to do the globbing - you want it to happen in the shell. Try this

```
set exec_call "cvs up *.tcl"
set caught [catch {eval exec -keepnewline $exec_call } result]
if { $caught } {
  #handle the error stored in $result
} else {
  #handle success
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want Tcl to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tcl 8.5, use the list expand syntax: `exec cvs up {*}[glob *.tcl]`

If you have an older Tcl: `eval [linsert [glob *.tcl] 0 exec cvs up]`
or `eval [concat exec cvs up [glob *.tcl]]`
The former is safer.